# Could not pin Azure Storage queue metrics to Grafana

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-storage-queues

I am using Azure storage queue and Grafina 9, I created a metrics in Azure dashboard success, I am trying to pin this metrics to Grafina, but metrics not shown in Grafina, I got error message like below:

```
request failed, status: 400 Bad Request, 
error: {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Detect invalid value: microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/queueservices for query parameter: 'metricnamespace', the value must be: Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts if the query parameter is provided, you can also skip this optional query parameter."}
```

Please let me know how to fix that.